# How to remove multiple filed laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I have my table data:

```
id  song_id   playlist_id
1     2          5
2     2          4
```

I want to remove it by if I give

```
song_id playlist_id
2          4         success
2          3          fail
```

Please help me thanks 
Noted: I use laravel custom query builder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
\DB::('table')->where('song_id',2)->where('playlist_id',4)->delete();
```